# PHP - Two MySQL connections, only second one works

Tags: php, mysql, connection, mysql-select-db

I've looked every where, probably googled every variation of my question I could come up with and I've tried all of the suggestions...  I'm trying to connect to two different DBs in two different locations ($local and $remote) and only the second one works.  Here is a sample of my code ("..." = hidden):

```
//-------------Local DB Connection:
    $local = mysql_connect("localhost","root","...");
    if (!$local)
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    $sel1 = mysql_select_db("new", $local);
//-------------Remote DB Connection:
    $remote = mysql_connect("...","...","...",true);
    if (!$remote)
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    $table = "...";

//---------function selecting from local:
    function fncGrabNemsis($ele,$val){
        mysql_select_db("new", $local);
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM new.tblvalues
        WHERE fldelement='$ele' AND fldcode='$val'",$local);
        $tmprow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        return (isset($tmprow['fldvariable'])?$tmprow['fldvariable']:$val);
    }

//----------Select run from Remote:
        mysql_select_db("ImdxTest", $remote);
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ImdxTest.$table WHERE ClientID = ... AND IncidentNum = '$fldINCID'", $remote) or die(mysql_error());
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

I've tried moving the mysql_select_db() function calls everywhere you can think of and just about everything else...  What happens is, I get php errors saying that $local is not defined or that the mysql function that are trying to use the $local connection are expecting parameters to be resources!?  I know for a fact that both connections work because individually they both work.  Only the second connection ($remote) works...  Thanks a lot for any suggestions!

Comment: BTW: Your query is open to SQL injections, try to use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fncGrabNemsis` needs the global variable `$local`:

```
    function fncGrabNemsis($ele,$val){
        global $local;
        mysql_select_db("new", $local);
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM new.tblvalues
        WHERE fldelement='$ele' AND fldcode='$val'",$local);
        $tmprow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        return (isset($tmprow['fldvariable'])?$tmprow['fldvariable']:$val);
    }
```

This should help you understand better: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 2):

`$local` is not available inside your function. Please read this: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

> [W]ithin user-defined functions a
>   local function scope is introduced.
>   Any variable used inside a function is
>   by default limited to the local
>   function scope.

In PHP, contrary to many other languages, outer scope is not avialble within functions. You must either pass the variable as an argument (preferred solution) or or use `gloabal` keyword, to import variable from global scope.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `fncGrabNemsis` from within a function.  When you open a function, you get a clean slate in terms of variables. Variables that previously existed no longer do. `$local` is now undefined.

The easy way around this is to set `$local` to the global value:

```
function fncGrabNemsis($ele,$val){
    global $local; 
    mysql_select_db("new", $local);
    ...
```

Globals are probably not a good idea, however.  You should rework your code so that they are unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

I see you are using `$local` inside a function, you should use `global $local` to reference the global scope `$local` variable from inside the function scope.